# Spawn in 2 different prefabs over a network Unity PUN 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am making an online multiplayer game. Once both players are ready, 2 DIFFERENT character prefabs are spawned into a room. The problem is that each player's device can't seem to read information about the other player's character.

They're spawned using the following code:

```
public class GameplayManager : MonoBehaviour

{

    public PhotonView view;

    public string BlueName;

    public string GreenName;

    public GameObject BluePlayer;

    public GameObject GreenPlayer;

    public Vector2 BlueSpawnPos = new Vector2(4.07f, 0.02f);

    public Vector2 GreenSpawnPos = new Vector2(3.97f, -0.02f);


  public void Start()
    {
        InstantiatePlayers();
        BluePlayer = GameObject.Find("blue soldier(Clone)");
        BlueName = PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.NickName;

        GreenPlayer = GameObject.Find("green soldier(Clone)");
        GreenName = PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.NickName;

        VictoryText = GameObject.Find("VictoryText").GetComponent<Text>();
    }


    public void InstantiatePlayers()
    {
        //If player 1:
        if (PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber == 1)
        {
            BluePlayer = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(BlueSoldier.name, BlueSpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
            Debug.Log("bname" + BlueName);
        }

        //if player 2:
        if (PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber == 2)
        {
            GreenPlayer = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(GreenSoldier.name, GreenSpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
            Debug.Log("gname" + GreenName);
        }
    }
```

I run this using the Unity Editor and a build to test. When I check the inspector in the editor, the 'Player' and 'Name' variables for the colour character in the editor have been updated correctly, but that of the other copy of the game are empty (i.e. if the editor is blue, 'BlueName' and 'BluePlayer' will be updated but 'GreenName' will be empty and 'GreenPlayer' will be 'None').

I suspect it's to do with my using if statements to spawn in characters, but I don't know if there's another way of spawning in multiple prefabs for multiple players.

Comment: There is a callback `OnPhotonInstantiate` which will notify you when something was spawned on the network, you could set the references from that function (Prefer to not use this function!).  You could also RPC from the photon view of the object that `this` client instantiated so that all the other copies can do their thing.  eg.  `myLocalPhotonView.RPC("SetNameRPC", RpcTarget.Others, PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.NickName);`

Comment: The main problem currently is that you try to find those instantiated objects before they have been spawned.  The PhotonNetwork.Instantiate function takes some time (networking time) before the object is instantiated on the client, however you try to set the references immediately on Start (this is why I pointed out the OnPhotonInstantiate callback).  A buffered RPC is better imo, but for quick testing and proof of concept I think the callback is fine.